# Spring synchronize saving to database with another instances

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 2 instances of my Spring boot application, I am using spring JPA.
Cron scheduler run method every one hour which
first, check if record is already updated, if it's updated it should skip and don't update, but it's updated anyway on both instances.
How to implement, something like synchronized, allow to read only when something is done?

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * ?", zone = "Europe/Paris")
public void updateServers() {
    applicationServerRepository.findAll().forEach(this::updateServerInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please explain the problem more detailed&exact.
But as I understand, you should:

- Or run the cron jobs only in one instance. (Back in 90ies we did it "manually", but spring-boot-profiles offer here great opportunity: decorate "all @scheduled beans" (re-factoring!?) with `@Profile("cronFooBar")`, and *activate*/add it *only on one* instance.)
- Or, if you also want cron jobs "load balanced", then you should find a way to synchronize/lock. (probably best *in* `updateServerInfo` or `updateServers`. (more details!? ..I am sure both instances will find "some object to lock on", at least the database (table, row, ..)))

As [proposed by Erkan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69988304/spring-synchronize-saving-to-database-with-another-instances/69989294#comment123721781_69989294)/[found on internet](https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring), with "little setup" (and discarding quartz!), you can have a handy annotation for this, like:

```
@SchedulerLock(name = "...", 
  lockAtLeastForString = "...", lockAtMostForString = "...")
```

---

But I suppose, it is also possible with spring-data-jpa (only & quartz) resources, like:

1. Add (pessimistic) locking:

   ```
   interface ApplicationServerRepository ... {

     @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
     @Query("select as from ApplicationService ...")
     findAllForCron();
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Catch it:

   ```
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * ?", zone = "Europe/Paris")
   public void updateServers() {
     try {
       applicationServerRepository
       .findAllForCron()
       .forEach(this::updateServerInfo);
     ​}
     catch​ (javax.persistence.PessimisticLockException plex) {
       logger.info("i get some coffee");
       return;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: You understand this problem. 
I want to lock my Object (ApplicationServer). Instance which will access it first, It give prefix like "already updated". And another instance should access, and see that it have this prefix, and just skip.
But, I don't know how to Lock it correctly, and unfortunately, 2 instances are updating, because it's running at this same time.

Comment: ok...but "ApplicationServer" are *two objects* (on two instances..in spring-boot!;)

Comment: How it works already:
- Instance which access first, take object(ApplicationServer) from database.
- Updates it with some values, and a prefix value like("already updated)
- Saves it to database.
I expect to lock this record in database, to prevent another instance to update it in same time.

Comment: If I will add some delay to another instance in scheduler it works like expected, but want just find a solution, how to perfect lock this record.

Comment: we are using shedlock for locking in order to run once with multiple instances.

Comment: @ErkanErkişi I think this is solution for this problem, I will implement this

Comment: @korallo yea it's usage is basic, just putting some annotations on method. and some table to db.

Comment: thanks for accept! the jpa-only solution is nor tested nor trusted, but just an approach/outline - feedback&experience welcome! :)